# What does this person do on the show?

Tags: meaning

I was watching an anime ("The Royal Tutor"), and I noticed someone with an interesting name (presumably a pen-name) - 子子子子 子子子, which as far as I can tell is a reference to "Neko no ko koneko, shishi no ko kojishi". So I tried to work out what role this person had in the show, and it was given as 予告脚本. As best I can manage, this seems to mean "preview script", so did this person really get a screen credit for writing the script to the next episode's preview, or is there another translation I've missed?

Comment: Have a look at http://nekojishikoneko.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/03/25/210533, which is the above-mentioned konenko's blog. There is a sentence: 「Gファンタジー」連載中の大人気王室コメディ『王室教師ハイネ』の次回予告コーナーの脚本を担当させて頂きました！ My attempted translation is: "GFantasy" serialised and very famous Royal Family comedy "The Royal Tutor" has a preview of the next installment segment(?) with me as script-writer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

予告 is a preview/trailer of the next episode of an anime or a drama, which is typically 15 seconds long. 脚本 is a script writer in this context. If the end credit really said something like `予告脚本 子子子子 子子子`, then that's the person who wrote the script of the preview of that episode. As you have probably guessed, there is not usually a dedicated writer for a 15-second preview clip, but that's the only possible interpretation.

From what I could google, [子【ね】子【こ】子【じ】子【し】 子【こ】子【ね】子【こ】](https://twitter.com/nekojishikoneko) is the pen name of a real novelist. This name must be a parody of the well-known wordplay [子【ね】子【こ】(の)子【こ】子【こ】子【ね】子【こ】](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%AD%90%E5%AD%90%E5%AD%90%E5%AD%90%E5%AD%90%E5%AD%90%E5%AD%90%E5%AD%90%E5%AD%90%E5%AD%90%E5%AD%90%E5%AD%90).

**EDIT**: Here's [a tweet](https://twitter.com/nekojishikoneko/status/845613242525237249) that says she was actually in charge of 予告脚本.

> 4／2から放送開始のTVアニメ『王室教師ハイネ』にて、次回予告コーナーの脚本を担当させて頂きました。毎話15秒ほどと短い時間ですが、１クール放送分を担当しております

Comment: So in other words, I was right, but I was doubting my interpretation because of how unlikely it seemed. Thanks!